# Chatting App with Media Sharing in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, whatsapp, viber

I want to make a chatting app with media sharing how can I do that in Android Studio. Do I need socket programming or what else, please help.

Answer (score 3):

Just go through Firebase codelab, the first android app they teach there is a chat app with media sharing ability.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/